# linq join throw an operation timeout error?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq

i have this query with multiple tables join, due to complex data relation,
in order to optimize the query, so i set linq ObjectTrackingEnabled 
to false, and build the query and join myself.

```
var tempapp = (
    from app in CTX.user_applications
    join user in CTX.user_lists on app.user_id equals user.user_id
    join pst in CTX.postings on app.posting_id equals pst.posting_id
    join job in CTX.job_ms on pst.job_id equals job.job_id
    join loc in CTX.job_location_ms on pst.location_id equals loc.job_location_id
    join jobcat in CTX.job_category_ms on pst.job_cat_id equals jobcat.job_category_id
    join offcat in CTX.office_category_ms on pst.office_cat_id equals offcat.office_category_id

    from appstat in CTX.app_status_ms.Where(stat => stat.app_status_id == app.app_status_id).DefaultIfEmpty() 

    from address in CTX.user_addresses.Where(addr => addr.user_id == user.user_id && addr.address_type == 0).DefaultIfEmpty()

    from state in CTX.state_ms.Where(st => st.state_id == address.state_id).DefaultIfEmpty()

    from edu in CTX.user_edus.Where(ed => ed.user_id == user.user_id).DefaultIfEmpty()

    select new  CustomObj
                {
                    application_id = app.user_app_id,
                    job_cat_id = jobcat.job_category_id,
                    job_cat_desc = jobcat.PSF_Desc,
                    off_cat_id = offcat.office_category_id,
                    off_cat_desc = offcat.PSF_Desc,
                    loc_id = loc.job_location_id,
                    loc_desc = loc.PSF_Desc,
                    job_id = job.job_id,
                    job_desc = job.PSF_Desc,
                    state_id = state.state_id,
                    state_desc = state.state_desc,

                    edu_lvl_id = edu.edu_lvl_id,
                    applied_date = app.applied_date,
                    manager_id = app.manager_id, 
                    gender_id = user.gender_id,
                    birthdate = user.birthday,
                    status_web = app.status_web,
                    status_psf = appstat.status_web,
                    user_id = user.user_id,
                    app_status_id  = app.app_status_id,
                    online_test_id = app.online_test_id

                }
    ).ToList();
```

i do not know why, but this query throw a timeout error:

> Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of
>   the operation or the server is not responding.

could someone point me, to fix this issue?

Comment: Linq will stop if the request takes more than 30secs. Set the [DataContext.CommandTimeout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.commandtimeout.aspx) to avoid that

Comment: @Nitro.de thanks, i will give that a shoot.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is your query just takes to long to execute. Like nitro.de already commented, you could set the CommandTimeout on your context to a higher value.

Because of the `ToList()` at the end of the statement, `LINQ` is querying all the data at once. Maybe you could omit the ToList and work with the `IEnumerable`, so the query is evaluated at a later time and each record is loaded when needed.

Another (maybe better) option would be to create a view in your database to join the data in SQL and query that view from code instead.